# How to observe work status with Android Jetpack WorkManager?

Tags: android, androidx, android-workmanager, observers

I'm trying to make an alarm app, which has a recycler view and each recycler item has a switch to schedule the alarm. The alarm uses WorkManager to schedule a future notification.

When I try scroll up and down my recycler view, it is using old view holders, so it will show a checked switch button on alarms which aren't actually scheduled.

To try to resolve this problem, I was thinking within onBind(), check if that item's work is being scheduled with WorkManager. If it is currently scheduled, have the switch checked. Otherwise, have the switch off.

I looked on Google's documents and found this https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/managing-work#observing, however, I am not sure how to work with ListenableFuture.

Can anyone give advice how I can check the status of a Work scheduled with WorkManager, and if it is the correct solution to perform this code within onBind() for the issue that I have (switch button being checked on other view holders)?

Answer (score 0):

See the next paragraph there ...one has to add an observer:

```
workManager

    .getWorkInfosForUniqueWork(jobName)  // make the promise; returns ListenableFuture 

    .observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), workInfo -> { // add an observer to the promise

        // update the adapter & notify, when it returns <List<WorkInfo>> or WorkInfo
    });
```